# Excel Geocoding -- extract coordinates from map

Tags: excel, geocoding

I've been trying to get longitude and latitude coordinates from Japanese addresses. There are a number of ways to do this, but most of them (such as Google Maps) only allow a limited number of queries a day (I have ~15000), and many do not support Japanese addresses.

Here is an example form of the addresses that I am using:

```
東京都千代田区丸の内1-9-1
```

However, recently I found that the 3D maps tool in Excel 365 can plot addresses on a map, and it's fast enough to handle all of my addresses. However, although I can see these points on the Excel, I don't know if there's a way to export these points to longitude-latitude coordinate pairs.

Does anyone know a way to get the longitude-latitude pairs from Excel's 3D maps feature?

Comment: This is probably done with Bing Maps that provide Location API and in particular support [japanese addresses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384099.aspx). With a free Basic Key Bing Maps limits you to [50,000 transactions per day and 125,000 transactions per year](https://www.microsoft.com/maps/create-a-bing-maps-key.aspx).

Comment: Not with excel, but this might help you if you can use Google Sheets http://willgeary.github.io/data/2016/11/04/Geocoding-with-Google-Sheets.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been working exactly same issue for weeks and i think best soluition is Google API